# If/Else Statement Change Image of a Radio Option when it isn't Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this Table with Radio Options and I'm trying to create a If/Else statement that if the radio option isn't checked and another one is then it will change the image to a X Mark (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX9Q3.png), if it is checked than it will change to an image of a check mark (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZFM.jpg).
Here's what I have so far:

```js
var radio1img1 = document.getElementById("radio1img1");
var radio1img2 = document.getElementById("radio1img2");

if (radio1img1.checked){
    changeImage('img1','https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZFM.jpg');
} else {
    changeImage('img1','https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX9Q3.png');
}
if (radio1img2.checked){
    changeImage('img2','https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZFM.jpg');
} else {
    changeImage('img2','https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX9Q3.png');
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td><b>B1</b></td>
    <td>
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1img1">
    <img align="center" name="radio1" class="theimage" id="img1" height="40px" width="40px" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGofFGc.png">
</input>
   </label>
     </td>
    <td>
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1img2">
    <img align="center" name="radio1" class="theimage" id="img2" height="40px" width="40px" src="http://i.imgur.com/DGofFGc.png">
</input>
   </label>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your `changeImage` function is missing in the snippet.

Comment: I'll edit it and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine, you just have to attach it to an event handler to make sure the code executes when the thing is ticked.

Using an `onclick` attribute is one of the many ways to do it (but not the best way).

```
<input onchange="someFuntion();" .. />
```

[Check out this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7zukdd3w/)

Comment: That works. Just one more question but how would I edit your code to accompany 3 radio buttons instead of 2?

Comment: You've got two conditions, one for each checkbox. Just add a third checkbox, condition and image and it should work fine with as many checkboxes you want.